# How to access data in an in-memory database?

Tags: groovy, h2

I have created an `in-memory database` using `H2` in groovy. I have also successfully added data in it. Now, I wanted to access the data in that database somewhere in my program like in a `service`, but I was not able to. Ive tried using the findAll(), getAll() methods, but nothing is returned, though the database has a content.

How could I fix this?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using an h2 database in groovy, you'll probably want to access it via JDBC through the [`groovy.sql.Sql`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) interface.  For example:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.168')

import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:h2:mem:db1", "sa", "sa", "org.h2.Driver")
println sql.rows("select * from MY_TABLE")
```